# Error running makefile to install ghostscript on ubuntu

Tags: ghostscript

This is very strange because I recently upgraded to Ghostscript 9.54 on another machine and I had no problem.  However on this machine when running my `make` file I get the error:

```
make gcc   -O2 -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef
-Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -fno-strict-aliasing -Werror=declaration-after-statement -fno-builtin -fno-common -Werror=return-type -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_DIRENT_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_DIR_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TIME_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TIMES_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBDL=1 -DGX_COLOR_INDEX_TYPE="unsigned long long" -D__USE_UNIX98=1  -DHAVE_RESTRICT=1 -fno-strict-aliasing
-DHAVE_POPEN_PROTO=1  -I./base -o ./obj/aux/genconf ./base/genconf.c  -lm -ldl  -rdynamic /usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file ./obj/aux/genconf: Permission denied collect2: error: ld returned 1
exit status base/unix-aux.mak:71: recipe for target 'obj/aux/genconf'
failed
```

Operating system is Ubuntu 18.04.

I have to manually upgrade rather than using `sudo apt-get` because that gets me 9.26 instead of the most recent version.

Answer (score -1):

The issue looks of permission denied for genconf. Would be good to provide full access.
Execute below command to give full access/permissions for entire directory.
**Please Note** as pointed out by @exa : This is not a good idea to give full permissions. 
You can provide the permissions as per your need and this was just for a test if this solves the issue.

`chmod -R 777 .` 
You can also give permission for specific file
`chmod -R 777 ./base/genconf.c`
Another way would also be to get a `.deb` installation file for specific version

Comment: Chmodding to 777 is rarely a good idea, this would better be avoided.

Comment: @exa Yes, this was just to test if this solves the issue. I have updated the answer.